# Using CuRand in ManagedCuda

Tags: cuda, managed-cuda

I'm currently working with ManagedCuda, and want to generate random numbers on the device. However I can't seem to find a simple example how to do this (browsing through objects in the `ManagedCuda.CudaRand` namespace and comparing with the C++ equivalent doesn't get me any further).

Actual question: How can I generate random numbers in a kernel when using managedCuda instead of the regular C++ API?

Comment: So did you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: @talonmies yes: How does curand work in managedCuda? How should I set it up to generate random numbers in a kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, you only want to use the device side API of CURAND, you will be then entirely independent of managedCuda: All you need to do in managedCuda is to allocate a large enough chunk of memory to save the current curandStates. You don’t even need a reference to managedCuda's CudaRand.dll.

Then you create an init kernel that calls for each thread `curand_init()` and then in your actual kernel you use `curand_normal()` or any of the other rand-functions. A step-by-step example is given in the curand manual in chapter 3.6.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later. However, guessing from the example the ammount of memory allocated is determined by the size of a curandState struct. There's probably no way to figure that out through managedCuda? (other than getting the sizeof on the device, storing that in device memory and querying from it in C#)

Comment: Apparently it's 48 bytes (in CUDA 7.5), figured that out with aformentioned sizeof method.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It was indeed as easy as allocating enough memory (kernelIterations * 48 bytes), setting the global (`__device__ curandState* randomState;`) to point to that data, calling a setup kernel to set it up (`curand_init(1234, i, 0, &randomState[i]);`) and then generate random floats (using `float f = curand_uniform(&randomState[i]);`).

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, to no avail. Are there any examples out there that I can actually load into Visual Studio with ManagedCuda?